# Problems with nested comments and figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, comments

Now this problem is probably too localized, but I do not see anywhere else to get help solving it. I have a large amount of important files, and these stopped compiling after switching from MikTex to TexLive (I reinstalled windows) after some fiddling I found out that some of the figures halt the compilation

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\includecomment{foo}
\includecomment{fuu}
\includecomment{figurer}
\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
\kant[1]
\begin{fuu}
\kant[3]
\begin{figurer}
\begin{figure}[!htbp] \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=6cm,fill=#1,opacity=0.4}}
\begin{scope}
  \node (D) at (2,4) {$\overline{\,F\,}\cap\overline{\,J\,}=2$}; 
\end{scope}
    \node (C) at (2,0) {};
      \tkzDrawCircle[R,fill=gray,opacity=0.4](C,5.25cm)
  \node [venn circle = red] (A) at (0,0) {};
  \node [venn circle = blue] (B) at (0:4cm) {};
  \node at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,B=1/2) {$F\cap J=10$};   
  \node  at (0,0) {$J=16$};
  \node  at (0:4cm) {$F=8$};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{figure}
\end{figurer}
\kant[4]
\end{fuu}
\end{foo}
\end{document}
```

Here is a somewhat minimal example, if the tikzpicture is change to something simpler
like a line, the file compiles just fine.

Now, my question is how do I get nested comments and the tikzpicture enviroment to become friends for all types of plots and diagrams?

Comment: I am using TL2012 in Ubuntu and had no problems. I am using the csv-Version of TikZ

Comment: I'm using TL2012 on cygwin/windows and get no error. What error do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit of digging reveals that the issue is not to do with TikZ, *etc.*, but to do with how the file reading/writing is working here. You can get the same issue with TeX Live on Windows with the demo file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\includecomment{foo}
\includecomment{fuu}
\includecomment{figurer}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\tracingall
\begin{foo}
\begin{fuu}
\begin{figurer}
A%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
B%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
C%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
D%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
E%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
F%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
G%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
H%%%%%
\end{figurer}
\end{fuu}
\end{foo}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

It is the number of characters that causes the issue, not the content (hence the fact that `%` shows the problem).

I reported this on the TeX Live mailing list, and the issue is the way that TeX Live's implementation of `\input` is coded on Windows. Akira Kakuto, who actually compiles the W32 binaries, said

> Confirmed. I can update TL2012 W32 binaries by fixed ones if needed
>   and allowed. (pdftex, tex, aleph and luatex). In W32, **input_line()** is
>   a bit different to skip byte order marks. By removing the difference,
>   the error disapears.

There should be an update for TeX Live to fix this.